# What's the difference between logic/if system and drive system of a display?

Tags: current, datasheet, power-consumption

I've been looking at the current consumption of a display and the datasheet says the following:

[image]

Can anyone tell me the difference between "drive system" and "logic/if system"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive system is what turns the pixels on and off, the logic system is what tells the drive system what to do, and the interface system is how the rest of the device talks to the logic system.